# asp.net SelectedIndexChanged for dropdownlist in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view with a `SelectedIndexChanged` event that fires when the user selects a row.

Now in the grid view row, I add a drop down list using `TemplateField`, and in the grid view `RowDataBound` event I add code for firing the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the drop down list.

So, when user click on drop down list the first event that fires is the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the grid view, then page goes into post back and the selection of drop down list is lost.

The `SelectedIndexChange` of drop down list fires only if user is faster on changing selection than page goes into post back.

I need that when user select a row with drop down list grid view's event wait for the drop down list selection and after first event that can fire is drop down list changing and at last grid view's `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Is this possible?

some code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grEventi" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
              ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
              CellPadding="3" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="grEventi_RowDataBound"
              onselectedindexchanged="grEventi_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedRow" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Elenco Eventi" HeaderText="Evento" />
        <asp:TemplateField  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="150" HeaderText="Data Inizio">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_data" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" > 
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_data" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_dat_SelectedIndexChanged"  ClientIDMode = "Static" class ="calendar">
                </asp:DropDownList>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>       
</asp:GridView>
```

code-behind:

```
protected void ddl_dat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your logic goes here
    string test = "";    
}

protected void grEventi_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference((Control)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));

        DropDownList ddl_dat = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl_data");
        ddl_dat.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "data inizio").ToString();
        ddl_dat.Visible = true;
        ddl_dat.DataTextFormatString = "{0: ddd d/MM/yyyy HH:mm}";
        ddl_dat.DataTextField = "data inizio";
        ddl_dat.DataValueField = "data inizio";

        ddl_dat.DataSource = mydata;
        // ddl_dat.AutoPostBack = true;
        ddl_dat.DataBind();                
    }
    else 
    {
        Label lbl_data = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_data");
        lbl_data.Visible = true;
        DateTime date=(DateTime)dr.Row["data inizio"];

        lbl_data.Text = date.ToString("ddd d/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    }
}

protected void grEventi_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //my logic code
}
```

Comment: _"fire is the selectindexchanged of the gridview, then page goes in postback and the selection of dropdownlist is lost"_ Why? Do you databind the `GridView` always on postbacks?

Comment: only if (!IsPostBack) I set datasource and do databind() on gridview

Comment: Is this your actual code?  I don't see why a PostBack would occur ***at all*** when you just click the DropDownList...

Comment: I edit my code, there was a line missing. The line is the clientscript in codebehind that cause the select, and so the postback.
I solved by remove this line and insert it only for row without dropdownlist